# Change background color of list item in Listview Titanium SDK

Tags: android, titanium

I am using the last version of Titanium SDK. I want to change the background of item in listview but it seems impossible.

I tried to use:

```
var item = $.section.getItemAt(index);
item.properties.backgroundColor = "#696969";
$.section.updateItemAt(index, item);
```

But I get the error said that the backgroundColor undefined...
I find a solution is that using a View with size of the list item and then set background color for this View to archive the same result. However, I can not find a way to access the view inside the list item.

Someone have done this please give me your opinion. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find out that I need to specific the properties element on the data item.

```
var item = {
            bind1: {
                text : value1
                },
            bind2: {
                text : value2
            },
            properties:{
                backgroundColor:"#aaaaaa"
            }
        };
```

Now the code:

```
var item = $.section.getItemAt(index);
item.properties.backgroundColor = "#696969";
$.section.updateItemAt(index, item);
```

works as expected.

:)